# Fragment back stack does not work when extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I'm using the new `AppCompatActivity` introduced in the `AppCompat` library version 22.1.

When I extend this Activity, the hardware back button no longer pops the back stack of my Fragments, it closes the Activity instead.

Here is how I'm changing fragments in my activity:

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment f) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, f);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

If I change `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` to `MainActivity extends Activity` the problem goes away and I am able to go backwards through my fragments.

Changing calls to `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` results in devices running Android < 5.0 losing the Material theme, which was the main reason for implementing `AppCompatActivity` in the first place.

The style referenced in my manifest `<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_light</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by overriding `onBackPressed()` in my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

If anybody has any insight into why this extra step is necessary when using `AppCompatActivity` I would be interested to know.

Comment: Have you also being able to understand why does if (savedInstanceState != null) {} construct is not called onCreate? I have been able to solve the problem by your code, but the update title is not being called.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. See @WoookLiu for the proper one.

Comment: because you extends "activity or fragmentactivity" you can't do with extends fragment, not resolve question about "how you can call Fragment back"

Answer (score 8):

use
    `getSupportFragmentManager()`
instead of
    `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: I tried this, but it resulted in losing the Material theme on devices < 5.0.  Updated the question to include this detail.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445012/material-design-backward-compatibility

Comment: Also, when use `supportFragmentManager` is nothing to do with `PreferenceFragment`

Answer (score -3):

Are you extending your app theme from `Theme.AppCompat.*`?

Comment: Yes. `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">...</style>`