# Android: change navigation arrow color in api 16 using 23.2.1 support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to change the color of the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (23.2.1 support library) arrow with api 16. The usual way of changing the back arrow color is like this:

```
final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);  

upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.somecolor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

However on api 16 the arrow stays the default white no matter what other I color I try to use. Is there another way of doing this for lower apis?

Edit - some stuff tried:

• changing the theme to .Light will make the arrows black, but doesn't help if I need a different color

• adding colorControlNormal in the theme will change the color, but if I want two different colored arrows in two different activities I have to support multiple themes.

• vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true apparently needs to be added to the gradle

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24445095/3678308

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me,

Put this in style:

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
<item name="color">@color/app_theme_color</item>
```

Comment: This works for the navdrawer icon. However all the toolbars stay with white back arrows.